# Как сделать регистрацию с использованием только javaScript?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать регистрацию пользователя на сайте? Сайт у меня на node.js. Я первый раз такую форму делаю и не знаю какой путь выбрать. Какой вариант лучше? Просто к кнопке "зарегистрироваться" подвязать эвент и в нем делать функцию? Или как-то использовать method="post" у формы?
UPD:
А как fetch() использовать? Я написал такой код, а что дальше с ним сделать - не знаю. Как я понял, на сервер запрос отправлен, а именно на сервер были отправлены данные формы. А что дальше с ними сделать? Обрабатывать форму в этом же коде? Моя цель - отправить запрос в базу данных sql, в которую внесется новый пользователь

```
const form = document.getElementById('reg');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Предотвращаем отправку формы по умолчанию

        const formData = new FormData(form);
        fetch('/registration', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(response => response.text()).then(data => {
            console.log(data); // Выводим ответ от сервера в консоль
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: *подвязать эвент и в нем делать функцию* - это как? *method="post" у формы* - проще вообще отказаться от стандартых методов формы и отправлять данные простым fetch

Comment: Как сейчас хотите, так и делайте. Вы хотите просто попрактиковаться с навыками, практиковаться можно по-всякому. Выберите вариант и сделайте